# Validate selected class before clicking next

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using an updated version of Janko at Warpspeeds Form to Wizard plugin.  http://www.ifadey.com/2012/06/form-to-wizard-jquery-plugin/

I am trying to get the form to validate so when all the images are selected you can proceed to click next.  The current working code I have provides a popup alert when they arent all selected which works as required, however when it does validate the next button does not work.

I am using validaBeforeNext.

A working JSfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/4Hkxy/3/

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 jQuery(function($){
            var $signupForm = $( '#multipage' );
 $signupForm.formToWizard({
                submitButton: 'SaveAccount',
                showProgress: true, //default value for showProgress is also true
                nextBtnName: 'Next',
                prevBtnName: 'Previous',
                showStepNo: false,
                validateBeforeNext: function() {
                    var selectedCount = $('.thumbnails.image_picker_selector:visible .selected').length;
        var totalCount = $('.thumbnails.image_picker_selector:visible').length;
    if(selectedCount != totalCount) {
        alert('please select an image per selection');
    }
              }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `validateBeforeNext` function must return `true` or `false`

```
if (selectedCount != totalCount) {
    alert('please select an image per selection');
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Then it will go to the next step.